# Deploying airsim based simulation on real world

Tags: airsim

As you know, Game of Drones is a simulation-based drone-racing competition built on AirSim. However, there is also an implementation side to it, i.e. deploying an actual drone for the task.

I am working for drone movement using airsim, I need help for the deployment of the code I used in simulation, in real drone, can I use the same code for real drone?
Thanks for any help!